# Replace css value with a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom, html-parsing

i need to change the height and top of my div to "$$height$$" and "$$top$$" before posting it for save in php. but jquery fails todo so (i think for mistake prevention):

```
$("#myobject").css("width", "$$height$$");
$("#myobject").css("top", "$$top$$");
```

i thought about regex but it is a little bit unsafe.

Comment: Where do those values come fom?

Comment: its a string "$$top$$" as is.

Comment: I believe that would be the job of an HTML parser on the server (assuming you want to save the markup to a db or file).

Comment: How are you handling this in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any browser will let you set invalid style properties, you'll probably have to do it manually by setting the style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `$("#myobject").attr("style", "width: $$height$$; top: $$top$$;");`?  It's a little "hacky", but the end result is the same and will allow you to add those values.

**Edit:** Actually, this will not work in IE . . . is still won't accept the invalid CSS values.  You may need to find an alternate approach.